# Bitwise Addition and Subtraction in a single sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I want to remove a flag from a bitwise fields and at the same time I want to add two flags

```
Declare @status int = 3
SET @status &= ~3 -- this will remove 1 and 2 if exists
SET @status |= 12 -- this will add 4 and 8 if exists
```

I want to do both of them together as this is used in an update statement like,

```
SET @status = (@status | 12 ) - (CASE WHEN (@status & 2 = 2) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) - (CASE WHEN (@status & 1 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Anyone knows how to do the subtraction part using bitwise operators along with addition part.

Something like,

```
SET @status |= 12 & ~2 --But this doesn't do what I want
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
SET @status = ((@status & ~3) | 12)
```